# Java Security set Provider to SSLContext

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate, x509

How can I set the Security Provider for a SSL Context?

My Code is like

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new XXX(), 1);///XXX is a Security Provider
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(p12FileName), p12FilePass.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientStore, p12FilePass.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());
```

If I remove the Provider `XXX` or set `SunEC` as the priority provider, everything works fine. But I can't do both due to some reason. Is there any way I can set the provider as `SunEC` in the SSL Context for the REST call without changing the first  line `Security.insertProviderAt(new XXX(), 1)`

Comment: “I can't do both due to some reason.”  How can you tell?

Comment: You can set the provider for the SSL/TLS _protocol_ using the overloads of SSLContext.getInstance -- but SunEC doesn't provide protocols. If your problem is using _ECC-based ciphersuite(s) in_ SSL/TLS, JSSE searches for the EC primitives using the (shared) list and cannot be specified; if a provider at position 1 is the lowest position that claims to implement ECDH and/or ECDSA and does them wrong, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Dave...not an expert in this cryptography area...Is there any available providers I can use in the SSLContext.getInstance...Do I need to create a custom provider.

Comment: I tried "SunJSSE" in the SSL Context and still not working.

Comment: Thanks Dave...I found the solution for this. I override the SocketFactory class and specified the Cipher